# Java sql parser with antlr

Tags: java, sql

I need in simple ANSI SQL parser and am looking for some instant solution. Does antlr have SQL grammar out of the box or should I write it on my own from scratch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this site. It has a java solution

http://jsqlparser.sourceforge.net/home.php

Johan

Comment: Fwiw, OP specifically asked about antlr; this project uses JavaCC.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an SQLite grammar for ANTLR4

https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/sqlite/SQLite.g4

Comment: This link is now broken.